# How to rectify discrepancy between chapter title and toc-entry

Tags: titlesec

As a compilation of the MWE below will illustrate, the *titleword*, which is intended to be smaller in the chapter title, becomes larger, and too large, in the toc-line. How can this be remedied?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand\SpSection{%
 \titleformat*{\section}{\centering\scshape\Large}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\SpSection
\chapter{A {\LARGE titleword} made  for more space}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is probably to use the optional argument of `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand\SpSection{%
 \titleformat*{\section}{\centering\scshape\Large}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\SpSection
\chapter[A titleword made for more space]{A {\LARGE titleword} made  for more space}\label{Platforms}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Then the chapter title looks like

[image]

but the ToC looks like

[image]

Comment: Rather amusing that an intentionally `\LARGE` titleword shows up smaller than the rest of the title.

Comment: Thanks! That serves the purpose. :) If someone comes up with an idea on how to match the titlewords in title and toc, that would be a nice bonus!

Comment: The bonus is \chapter[A {\small titleword} made for more space]{A {\LARGE titleword} made  for more space} :)